# out of three libraries, require.js is failing to load one; how can I find out why?

Tags: coffeescript, requirejs

I've got three libraries that I am loading with require.js:

```
require(['lib/alpha', "lib/delta", "lib/gamma"], (alpha, delta, gamma) ->
  # initialize objects from libraries etc.
```

They all look pretty similar:

```
# names changed for IP protection, so this code may look funny

define(->
  class alpha
    constructor: ({@type, @user, @data}) ->
      @time = new Date()
)

define(->
  class delta
    constructor: ({@logger, @config, @socket, @util}) ->
      #@logger.debug arguments
      @room = null
      (@util ?= {}).inspect ?= JSON.stringify

      # more functions ...
)

define(->
  class gamma
    alphas = null
    constructor: ({@logger, @config, @alphaUtility, @newId}) ->
      throw 'alpha utility not defined' unless @alphaUtility?

    # more functions ...
)
```

However, suddenly and for no reason that I can discern, `delta` is suddenly not loading via `require`. It's just `undefined` in the callback.

Relevant details:

- I haven't touched the code in `delta` in weeks
- Rolling back to code from last week has no effect
- Loading in a different order or loading `delta` by itself has no effect
- The js file is present on the server and loads fine when I call the URL directly
- All the files are in the same folder
- Require is throwing no errors
- There are no errors in the console

I'm stumped here, how can I figure out why require won't load this file? I've stepped through the code a bit it's 2k lines so determining where it's failing is difficult.

Require 2.1.8 (current as of 9/24/2013)

Comment: Any errors in the console? (Not just thrown errors, but, e.g. 404 errors)

Comment: @StephenThomas not a thing; updated OP

Comment: @StephenThomas there's GETs in the network panel for alpha and gamma but not delta. That's peculiar...

Comment: @jcollum Have you tried loading the script via `script` tag? I don't see why this shouldn't work when calling the URL directly works, but I have no other ideas (although it is possible that the server reacts differently to AJAX requests).

Comment: I did make some progress: putting the files in a subfolder (/lib/u/alpha) means they are suddenly loading fine. WTF.

Comment: maybe there was a cached copy of delta in the browser (requireJS is **very** aggressive with caching) and the cached copy was causing problems. By changing the path, you would have forced requireJS to abandon the cached copy

Comment: do you think that would have propagated across a Ctrl-F5? I don't think that explains why I would get undefined... if it had a cached copy of the file, wouldn't it return that instead of undef?

Comment: @StephenThomas dev seems to think this is related to Chrome 29. Will report back if I figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while and there haven't been any answers, so I'll write one.

The `require.js` dev suggested that this may have been a bug in Chrome 29. Since Chrome has now bumped to v30 and this issue has stopped happening, I have to assume that it is fixed.